# MySQL data transfer to different schema

Tags: mysql, migration

We have two servers: one for the developer (me) and one for the tester.

While working on the app, I sometimes make little changes in tables's schemas. (Like a new field, or a field type)

I'm trying to find a way to update the TEST's schema from the DEV without altering the TEST data.

I tried to dump the DEV structure only, execute it on the `TEST db`, and then fill it with the TEST data. But the new `schema` is replaced with the old `TEST schema`...

Do you have a way to do that ?
Or will my tester be forced to fill the database everytime we update?

Thanks...

Comment: This might can be solved a layer above database. Most frameworks are offering helper for migration of database.

Comment: I must be missing something as cant you simply run the same ALTER TABLE statement on TEST that you ran on DEV ? if you are adding a new column or changing the datatype then this should be fine as a script.

Comment: Because my workflow is really bad. I have no changelog, and can't remember the changes I made. That's why I'm looking for an automated solution...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/) (from one of the founders of stackexchange). Be **ABSOLUTELY** sure to follow the five links therein to K. Scott Allen's series on "the philosophy and practice of database version control" - in the top 1-2% of the best technical writing that I have ever read.

There are many tools (see [here](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2011/01/11/database-version-control/) and [here](http://secretgeek.net/dbcontrol)) for this (pay and Open Source) - the one that seems to get the most coverage around here is [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) (disclaimer - haven't used any - my DB versioning involved using v. old Unix VCS software.).

Comment: Thanks for these links. I'm clearly not enough skilled for the moment and I have no time to level up to be able to do something like this, so I think that I will keep making changes manually for this project. But they will be very helpful in some weeks.

Comment: One thing I do know about IT projects is that they're like babies - they tend to grow, and if you don't impose discipline now, it'll be much more difficult later on :-). Seriously, if you don't have **some** sort of procedure, you'll soon be in the position of constantly having to fire-fight and get less and less work done. Start with your ordinary VCS - you **do** have one, right? Start putting scripts/updates into so that you can update incrementally, rather than having to "fill the database everytime we update". Best of luck.

Comment: In fact, I never used a VCS (shame on me). I tried GIT but wasn't able to understand it quickly. I know I will need one soon but it's hard to find the time.

Comment: Find it now, or find more later. Git is complex (even [Torvalds](http://typicalprogrammer.com/linus-torvalds-goes-off-on-linux-and-git/) says so - and he wrote it!) - try Subversion maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I am using **`mysqldbcompare`** to check the difference between the two databases. I hope it may help:

```
mysqldbcompare --server1=username:password@hostname:3306 --server2=username:pasword@localhost:3306 DB1:DB1 --run-all-test --difftype=sql --skip-checksum-table --skip-row-count --skip-data-check  changes-for=server2
```

- Replace the `DB1:DB1` with `database name`.
- Replace the `username, password, port and hostname`.
- This parameters will produce output in `SQL format` and it does not
  check the table data and row count difference.
- Send this output to file. Verify and execute the file in `server2.`

You may check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldbcompare.html) for official documentation. **Give it a try!!!**

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider [Skeema](https://www.skeema.io).

> Skeema is a pure-SQL schema management utility. Simply track your desired schema state in a repo of CREATE statements, and the tool figures out how to apply any changes to your tables and routines. You won't need to code migrations, use obscure DSLs, or write verbose XML ever again.

In other words, you can use your current tables in development as the canonical reference, and Skeema will figure out what ALTER TABLE statements are needed to upgrade the testing schema to match. Sort of similar to mysqldbcompare in the Rathish's answer, but probably more featureful.